# CUDA 2D matrix location/indexing behave differently for dataframe.to_numpy() and numpy 2D array

Tags: python, pandas, cuda, pycuda

I have tried the below code and the results are different if I create a numpy 2D array myself and using dataframe.to_numpy() to create 2D array.  Could anyone help to explain why?

The result if I use `a = input_matrix.to_numpy()` or `a = np.array([[1, 100, 200, 300], [1, 100, 200, 300], [1, 100, 200, 300]])` are different

`a = input_matrix.to_numpy()` returns the below.  I even tried transposing a (by a = a.T) after to_numpy() but the output is still the same.  Could anyone suggest a way which can transpose that matrix from to_numpy successfully?

```
input array is
[[  1. 100. 200. 300.]
 [  1. 100. 200. 300.]
 [  1. 100. 200. 300.]]
returned array is
[  1.   1.   1. 100. 200. 300.]
```

while `a = np.array([[1, 100, 200, 300], [1, 100, 200, 300], [1, 100, 200, 300]])` returns the below

```
input array is
[[  1. 100. 200. 300.]
 [  1. 100. 200. 300.]
 [  1. 100. 200. 300.]]
returned array is
[  1. 100. 200. 300. 200. 100.]
```

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

_path = r"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\Hostx64\x64"

if os.system("cl.exe"):
    os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + _path
if os.system("cl.exe"):
    raise RuntimeError("cl.exe still not found, path probably incorrect")

input_matrix = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [1, 1, 1], 'b': [100, 100, 100], 'c': [200, 200, 200], 'd': [300, 300, 300]})
a = input_matrix.to_numpy()
# a = np.array([[1, 100, 200, 300], [1, 100, 200, 300], [1, 100, 200, 300]])
a = a.astype(np.float32)
print('input array is')
print(a)
a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(a_gpu, a)

a_out = np.zeros(6)
a_out = a_out.astype(np.float32)
a_out_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a_out.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(a_out_gpu, a_out)

mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void matrix_location_trial(float *in_matrix, float *out_matrix)
  {
     out_matrix[0] = in_matrix[0];
     out_matrix[1] = in_matrix[1];
     out_matrix[2] = in_matrix[2];
     out_matrix[3] = in_matrix[3];
     out_matrix[4] = in_matrix[6];
     out_matrix[5] = in_matrix[9];
  }
  """)
      
func = mod.get_function("matrix_location_trial")
func(a_gpu, a_out_gpu, block=(1,1,1))

returned_array = np.empty_like(a_out)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(returned_array, a_out_gpu)
print('returned array is')
print(returned_array)
```

Comment: Your input array when using .to_numpy() has 3 rows x 4 columns and while creating manually with NumPy has 4 rows x 4 columns. If you pass different input in both cases, the output will differ.

Comment: sorry for the mistake there, but after correcting it to "a = np.array([[1, 100, 200, 300], [1, 100, 200, 300], [1, 100, 200, 300]])", it still shows different returned result

Comment: Transposing in numpy doesn't change the underlying storage order, that is why using the transpose doesn't change anything

Comment: Then is there any other way to do transposing which can change the underlying storage order?

Answer (score 3):

The storage order in both cases is different:

1. Dataframe

```
input_matrix = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'a': [1, 1, 1], 
        'b': [100, 100, 100], 
        'c': [200, 200, 200], 
        'd': [300, 300, 300]
    }
)
a = input_matrix.to_numpy().astype(np.float32)
print(a.flags)
```

Output:

```
C_CONTIGUOUS : False
F_CONTIGUOUS : True
OWNDATA : True
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

2. NumPy array

```
a = np.array(
    [[1, 100, 200, 300], [1, 100, 200, 300], [1, 100, 200, 300]],
    dtype=np.float32
)
print(a.flags)
```

Output:

```
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : True
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

The difference in both cases here is in the values of flags `C_CONTIGUOUS` and `F_CONTIGUOUS`.

Arrays created using `np.array()` are `C_CONTIGUOUS` by default whereas the same cannot be guaranteed for numpy arrays created using other ways, like from `input_matrix.to_numpy()` in this case.

To resolve this issue, you just have to make the array `C_CONTIGUOUS` again before you copy the data to GPU memory like this:

```
a = input_matrix.to_numpy()
a = a.astype(np.float32)

# Change order to C_CONTIGUOUS
a = a.copy(order="C")

print('input array is')
print(a)
a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(a_gpu, a)
```

After adding that line, I was able to get the following output in both cases:

```
[[  1. 100. 200.]
[300. 200. 100.]]
```

The difference between which of the flags `C_CONTIGUOUS` and `F_CONTIGUOUS` is True for an array is related to how the array is stored in memory. C language stores data in Row-major order while Fortran stores it in Column-major order.

NumPy supports storing your data in both ways. You can read more about storage [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).